# drop function is making problem for me on this program why?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-visualization

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
acsv=pd.read_csv('full_data.csv')
acsv.drop([2,5],axis=0,inplace=True)
booliens=[]
for i in acsv.new_deaths:
    tip=str(i)
    if "nan" in tip:
        booliens.append(False)
    else:
        booliens.append(True)

booliens=pd.Series(booliens)

booliens.shape
```

shape of booliens series:(2865,)

```
acsv.shape
```

shape of acsv DataFrame:(2865, 6)

```
acsv[booliens]
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\Asgar Aliyev\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:1: UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexingError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-99a794a359e7> in <module>
----> 1 acsv[booliens]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2789         # Do we have a (boolean) 1d indexer?
   2790         if com.is_bool_indexer(key):
-> 2791             return self._getitem_bool_array(key)
   2792 
   2793         # We are left with two options: a single key, and a collection of keys,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _getitem_bool_array(self, key)
   2841         # check_bool_indexer will throw exception if Series key cannot
   2842         # be reindexed to match DataFrame rows
-> 2843         key = check_bool_indexer(self.index, key)
   2844         indexer = key.nonzero()[0]
   2845         return self._take_with_is_copy(indexer, axis=0)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in check_bool_indexer(index, key)
   2315         if mask.any():
   2316             raise IndexingError(
-> 2317                 "Unalignable boolean Series provided as "
   2318                 "indexer (index of the boolean Series and of "
   2319                 "the indexed object do not match)."

IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).
```

first value of booliens and acsv is same.it should work when i write  this command 'acsv[booliens]' . But it deosnt .when i remove

```
acsv.drop([2,5],axis=0,inplace=True)
```

this line i don't get any error and it  work well.and getting same shapes

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The code you shared is not idiomatic Pandas, and I wouldn't be surprised if it contributed to the problem.

Comment: Try `acsv.loc[booliens]` or `acsv.loc[booliens,:]`.

Comment: `shape of booliens DataFrame:(2865,)` - is `booliens` a DataFrame or a Series?

Comment: You should read through and practice the examples in the [Indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html) section of the User Guide in the docs. Particularly the Boolean indexing section - but start at the beginning.

Comment: `acsv.new_deaths.notna()`? or `acsv[acsv.new_deaths.notna()]`

Comment: wwii it is Series yeah.i wrote wrong

Answer (score 0):

After dropping some rows from the DataFrame, the remaining index values are still the original ones, so the index is no longer an uninterrupted sequence of all natural numbers from 0 to n-1. That's why it does not match the index of your Boolean Series.

So, after the `acsv.drop(...)` line, insert this:

```
acsv.index = range(len(acsv))
```

EDIT:

Or, as ansev suggested below, the more elegant

```
acsv = acsv.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: OP said that the both have the same length along the first axis. And `boolien` is a boolean Series, not a Series of integers.

Comment: I know, but the Boolean Series has an index of integers, doesn't it?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing

Comment: anyway this is not a good solution, there are solutions to check if a series contains NaN

Comment: also `acsv = acsv.reset_index(drop=True)` more elegant

Comment: wwii, the documentation you linked to does not cover indexing by a Boolean Series. I know that the OP's problem does not arise when you index by a plain Boolean vector. So an alternative solution would be to change the last line to `acsv[list(booliens)]`.

Comment: Thanks ansev, I added your suggestion to the answer.